# Setting dimensions of <img> fallback for <source> inside <picture>, for SEO/page loading time

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images, srcset

Using the code below, I am trying to achieve this:

- allow the browser to choose between WEBP `<source>` and JPEG in`<img>` (as fallback)
- display the image 754px wide for viewport widths >1058px, or, for smaller viewports, select one of the five images automatically and stretch to viewport width.
- have an `src` attribute of `<img>` in place, which points to a low-res lazyload version
- specify `width` and `height` of image in HTML specified for SEO/UX reasons (more below).

  ```
  <div>
  <picture>
  <source type="image/webp" 
       data-srcset="
          image_100.webp 100w, 
          image_200.webp 200w, 
          image_400.webp 400w, 
          image_600.webp 600w,
          image_754.webp 754w" 
          data-sizes="(min-width: 1058px) 1000px, 100%" />
  <img data-srcset="
          image_100.png 100w, 
          image_200.png 200w, 
          image_400.png 400w, 
          image_600.png 600w,
          image_754.png 754w" 
          data-sizes="(min-width: 1058px) 1000px, 100%" 
          src="image_min.png" width="1000" height="300" alt="image_alt" />
  </picture>
  </div>
  ```

Why are there a `data-` prefixes, you ask? I want to use a lazyloading script, which will remove them, at the right time, when the image should be displayed.

Before the lazyloading script kicks in, the browser will ignore the `<source>` element, because proper `srcset` and `sizes` will be absent at that point. The browser will also ignore `data-srcset` and `data-sizes` of `<img>`, and will, therefore, display a low-res/placeholder image as defined in `src`.

Knowing the image dimensions and thus w/h ratio, I also want to supply these, in HTML, so that the browser knows what space to reserve for the image during loading time, **before** the images are loaded, to prevent re-rendering.

Simply setting absolute values of the image into `style` or into `width` and `height` attributes of the `<img>`, are only valid for viewport width >1058px. Otherwise, the dimensions are relative to viewport size. So, I want to tell the browser, that the image will have a width 100% and height 30% of width of parent `<div>`, which si valid in all cases.

I know that there is a css `padding-top` trick, to keep aspect ratio of a div, but I'm not sure I can use it in theis scenario, since it actually creates a padding above the image.

Any other ideas on setting the fallback image dimension?

Comment: You can absolutely use the padding trick - but you need to position the image absolutely inside the wrapping div - that way it wont create a padding above the image - only serve as a placeholder.

Comment: @ajobi, you are right, the padding trick works, when the `<div>`  is parent for `<img>`. However, I can't get this to work with `<picture>`.

Comment: Could you create a sandbox example of that ? jsfiddle or something. I might check it later

Comment: @ajobi, Sorry, my bad. I must have messed up my code. The `padding-top` hack works even with `<img>` inside `<picture>`. So thank you!

Comment: Cool ! congratulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so a plausible answer is, after all, wrapping the `<picture>` in a `<div>` container and applying CSS, including the `padding-top` hack, to maintain its' aspect ratio:

```
<div style="position:relative;"width:100%;padding-top:33%>
<picture>
<source type="image/webp" 
     srcset="
        image_100.webp 100w, 
        image_200.webp 200w, 
        image_400.webp 400w, 
        image_600.webp 600w,
        image_754.webp 754w" 
        sizes="(min-width: 1058px) 1000px, 100%" />
<img srcset="
        image_100.png 100w, 
        image_200.png 200w, 
        image_400.png 400w, 
        image_600.png 600w,
        image_754.png 754w" 
        sizes="(min-width: 1058px) 1000px, 100%" 
        src="image_min.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute" alt="image_alt" />
</picture>
</div>
```

- CSS of the fallback `<img>`: `width` and `height` set to 100%, and `position:absolute`
- The `<div>` wrapper must be CSS `position:relative`, for the image to be positioned  inside it "absolutely".
- The `<div>` must have `width` and `padding-top` set to reflect the dimensions/aspect ratio of the image.
- The CSS does not need to be defined inline, and so the size of the div wrapper can be set differently for different viewport sizes using media queries.

It works as follows:

The `<img>` element fills up the `<div>` wrapper completely. Thanks to `position:absolute`, the `padding-top` of the `<div>` wrapper has no effect on position of the image. The percentage value of `padding-top` makes it relative to the element **width**, so aspect ratio remains constant (e.g. `padding-top` set to 100% would make the wrapper always square).

The main benefit for SEO/UX:

No matter what the `sizes` and the `srcset` values are, if the dimensions (thus aspect ratio) are known, we can create a placeholder using CSS of the fallback `<img>`, and so reserving space for an image which has not yet been loaded, or even chosen by the browser from the `srcset`.

Ultimately this will prevent annoying changes in page layout, caused by images being painted on a page which has alreadey been rendered.